# Find all the steps in feature files that do not have step method definitions?

Tags: java, continuous-integration, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-jvm

We use CucumberJVM in our test automation project. Recently we moved out all the feature files from the project and are maintaining them in a separate repository.

Considering this I am looking for a way to detect and output list of all the steps in feature files which do not have step method definitions.

I am looking at a linting like utility which would check for all un-implemented scenario steps in feature files and display which ones do not have step methods in a particular package of step classes.

Is there any existing plugin/tool that does this?

Comment: There is dryrun option if it's set to true then it tells us which steps do not have steps implementation, are you looking something different

Comment: Simply running the tests will also log all steps which don't have step definitions yet. Doing so with dryrun option set to true will generate this output without actually running the tests.